# Detect when code is called while process is terminating (C/C++)

Tags: c

In C/C++ applications, lots of code may run when an application is in the process of terminating. This includes handlers installed via `atexit()`, global variables with destructors in C++ and C++11-style `thread_local` variables of fancy types with destructors.

I am interested in detecting whether the application is in the process of shutting down, e.g. via a hypothetical function of the signature.

```c
/// returns 1 if the application is in the process of exit()-ing
extern int is_shutting_down();
```

Obviously this particular function does not exist, but I am wondering: is this still possible somehow? I am interested in both portable and non-portable (e.g., Linux/Windows/macOS-specific) solutions.

A simple solution to this problem would be to set a global variable before returning from `main()` or calling `exit()`. In my case, that is not an option since I do not have control over the application. My code runs in a shared library that is `dlopened()`, and which has no control over when the program exits.

Comment: Detecting by what? Another program? Your program has already left the main function

Comment: C or C++?  They are two **very** different languages, and the answers could very well be different for each.

Comment: I suspect that an answer, if it exists, would be more at the C-level than the C++ one.

Comment: @WenzelJakob answer first my questions - read the comments. What do you mean by"Certain operations may not be legal in this context,"  what operations? Who would perform that operations?

Comment: You could set a global flag to true at the start of main saying "we're running normally", then set it to false when you exit main. From anything called by your `atexit` handler (or others) you should then be able to check whether main's already out

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues what for? If handlers are called then you are sure that the program is terminating.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues: Process termination is not initiated only by exiting `main`. A program might also call `exit` or `quick_exit`, and this might be done by library routines beyond the easy control of the main program.

Comment: @0___________: Re “Detecting by what?”: Detected by code in routines that might be called by exit handlers (or might be called by other code, hence they do not inherently know whether the program is exiting or not).

Comment: @tadman interestingly i do not know who is going to detect this state. The question is how to detect it

Comment: Normally you should not care. The shutdown process, if there is one, should kill off any threads or event loops that could have unwanted side-effects. In terms of more primitive behaviour, you must enumerate *why* your process is shutting down. Is this an internally-initiated operation? A `SIG` signal? A user-interface request like Alt+F4 or ⌘Q? Normally functions like `atexit` are called way, way too late in the process, and they're there for any last-ditch things you might need to do before a possibly very hard landing.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if atexit handler is called then you are in the process of terminating. What can you detect more?

Comment: @0___________ What about asynchronous signals (invoked while executing main or an atexit handler)?

Comment: @0___________: Re “if atexit handler is called then you are in the process of terminating”: So? How do you know if an `atexit` handler is called? Say you have some routine `foo` that you registered as a callback with a third-party library. The library might register its own exit handler. When some error in your program occurs, you call `exit`. Then the library’s exit handler calls the callback routine. How does your routine `foo` know it is called from an exit handler rather than from ordinary code?

Comment: @0___________ I presume they have some functions that could be called during normal operation and also from shutdown functions, and they want them to do something different during shutdown.

Comment: @EricPostpischil registered handler is called when program terminates.  It does not have to know. Simply write separate functions to handle termination.

Comment: @0___________: You can’t have a separate function for the callback. You register one callback with the library and cannot control whether the library calls it from ordinary code or from an exit handler. Therefore you want a way to detect whether it is called after a program exit has been initiated.

Comment: @Barmar if a function can be called from the handler and not from the handler simply pass the parameter to that function. It is the cleanest way of doing it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Why do you want to call atexit callback (handler function) from normal code?

Comment: @0___________: It is not an `atexit` callback. It is a callback from the library.

Comment: @EricPostpischil what callback - be more specific.

Comment: Since you are asking about specifics: consider a C++ type, whose destructor decreases the reference count of a Python object (via `Py_DECREF`). When the process is terminating, such destructors may be called as part of static shutdown logic. If Python initiated a call to `exit()`, then re-entrant usage of Python API will crash the process. I don't want to invite a discussion of "is it a good design to do this", here. Clearly, it is not. Besides, the question is much broader than this specific use case.

Comment: Title, body and tag of this question indicate 'C', yet the usage examples given all seem to refer to C++... Is this a misrepresentation?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think we are approaching the land of XY problems

Comment: The question does not depend on any of these specifics. Can we please stop this weird meta-discussion?

Comment: @WenzelJakob so what is your problem? The question is not clear at all. What do you want to archive? Who is detecting? I believe that you do not know either

Answer (score 1):

Create a handler

```
void terminateHandler(int signal) {
    // the application is being terminated
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Register the handler

```
int main() {
    if (signal(SIGTERM, terminateHandler) == SIG_ERR) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: This catches `SIGTERM`, but neither `exit()` nor returning from `main()` generate `SIGTERM`.